# Raspberry Pi - Activate relay by phone

Tags: relay

I'd like to set up a system to control a relay via land line.  My goal is to somehow run a landline to the Raspberry Pi unit and have it trip a relay when the number is called and a DTMF sequence is entered.  Is this something that is feasible?  This is designed to remotely activate a tornado siren where the site is too far away to activate by radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this without a RasPi.  Do a Duck Duck Go for "DTMF Decoder" and you will find many products that take a direct DTMF audio signal from a land line and, depending on the code, activate one of several relays.  A typical 4 relay control board sells for less than $20.  Most of them are designed to control devices in your home from a remote location, and they should be a good match for your application.

Comment: For those that are interested in more than just controlling relays, it's also possible to make your RPi a part of the system - for example, execute a timed sequence of relay actions, or start a program on the RPi. If one wants to get his RPi involved in a "DTMF loop", ideas are available for the cost of a [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=DTMF+decoder+Raspberry+Pi&ia=web).